# Predicting a Chi-Square Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, state-space-models

Assume that $W(t)$ is a one-parameter stochastic process given by
$W(t) := X_1^2(t) + X_2^2(t)$ where $X_i(t)$ are independent copies of
a stationary gaussian process with known covariance function. This is
a special case of a *chi-square process* ($\chi^2$-process) for which
interesting known facts can be found on the web. Yet

1. What method(s) can be used to compute predictions for $W(t)$?
2. If moreover each $X_i(t)$ has a state-space representation, can 
   a specific filtering algorithm be designed for $W(t)$?

Comment: For the second question, the context seems a good playground for the *Rao-Blackwellized particle filter*.