# Simulate Gaussian variables conditional on their sum of squares

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, random-generation, chi-squared-distribution, conditioning

Consider a $d$-dimensional Gaussian random vector $\mathbf{Z}=[Z_i]_i$
with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance matrix
$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. What would be the more efficient method(s) to
simulate $\mathbf{Z}$ conditional on the sum of squares of its
components $Y := Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + \dots + Z_d^2$? The independent case
with $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ diagonal can be of interest.

My first simple attempt is via importance sampling using as importance
distribution a Von Mises distribution on the sphere $\{\mathbf{z}: \:
\|\mathbf{z}\|^2 = Y\}$ with pdf $g(\mathbf{z}) \propto \exp\{
\boldsymbol{\theta}^\top \mathbf{z}\}$, choosing $\boldsymbol{\theta}
= \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}$.  This question relates
to my question about the [chi-square
process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/219925/10479).

Comment: Importance sampling does not allow you to simulate a given distribution but only and at best to approximate moments from this distribution. To simulate exactly from your target, you should seek an accept-reject method, using a proposal that is supported by the sphere.

Comment: @Xi'an. Oh yes, thank you. I had in mind using  particles for the
specific filtering problem, hence using resampling. A concern is the ratio of the two pdf, which can be computed exactly with for the Von Mises'.

Comment: But can the ratio be bounded? This is the important issue for exact simulation. Actually, given the von Mises density, it is likely to be bounded.

Comment: I think that when $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is chosen as I proposed the
ratio of pdf target / proposal is $\propto \exp\{-\mathbf{z}^\top
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{z} / 2\}$ so the maximum and minimum
relate to those of the Rayleigh quotient hence to the eigenvalues of
$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. When $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is scalar the ratio
is constant hence must be $1$.

Comment: I'd be interesting in seeing this even for the cases with $d=2$; $\mu=(1,1)$ or $\mu=(0,1)$; $\Sigma=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1}$

Comment: When $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is a scalar diagonal matrix the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{Z} / \sqrt{Y}$ is a von Mises-Fisher distribution, available e.g. in the **movMF** R package. This is the easy case.